# Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Cloud Shell "Boost" feature missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

When I opened my GCP cloud shell today the "boost" feature was gone! Tried all the menus, even tried the option given here : [Enabling Google Cloud Shell "boost" mode via gcloud cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614438/enabling-google-cloud-shell-boost-mode-via-gcloud-cli)   but still no progress. Does someone else also have the same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cloud Shell boost mode feature option is no longer available or needed. They removed that feature, also I noticed that they removed the boost mode information in Google Cloud Shell official documentation website but they upgraded/boosted everyone's Cloud Shell.

I saw the changes of my Cloud Shell memory was upgraded from before - `1.7G(default) / 3.7G(boosted)` to present - `15G or 16GB(default mode)`. To check it in your Cloud Shell run the command `free -h`.

I'll update my answer once I have a link or more information or they provide documentation about this.

Comment: Previously, Google allocated a `g1-small` instance size for Cloud Shell and an `n1-standard-1` for boost mode. Your link does not refer to boost mode. Do you have another link? Do you know what instance size is now allocated for Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 0):

Running the `free -h` command produced this result in my Cloud Shell as of December, 2020:

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         15Gi       1.0Gi        12Gi       4.0Mi       2.6Gi        14Gi
```